# Using www_open_url/1

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I understand that `www_open_url/1` should launch my default browser and go to a webpage. But my ubuntu computer does not do this. If I start prolog normally I get the error 'Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console' . If I launch swipl as sudo it just returns `true` but does not launch a browser. I would like to use this predicate normally not as sudo. Here is a trace:

```
www_open_url('http://www.bbc.co.uk').
Call: (6) www_browser:www_open_url('http://www.bbc.co.uk') ? creep
Call: (7) current_prolog_flag(browser, _G397) ? creep
Fail: (7) current_prolog_flag(browser, _G397) ? creep
Redo: (6) www_browser:www_open_url('http://www.bbc.co.uk') ? creep
Call: (7) getenv('BROWSER', _G397) ? creep
Fail: (7) getenv('BROWSER', _G397) ? creep
Redo: (6) www_browser:www_open_url('http://www.bbc.co.uk') ? creep
Call: (7) www_browser:open_command(_G396) ? creep
Exit: (7) www_browser:open_command('gnome-open') ? creep
Call: (7) www_browser:has_command('gnome-open') ? creep
Call: (8) www_browser:command_cache('gnome-open', _G397) ? creep
Exit: (8) www_browser:command_cache('gnome-open', -) ? creep
Call: (8) (-)\== (-) ? creep
Fail: (8) (-)\== (-) ? creep
Fail: (7) www_browser:has_command('gnome-open') ? creep
Redo: (7) www_browser:open_command(_G396) ? creep
Exit: (7) www_browser:open_command(open) ? creep
Call: (7) www_browser:has_command(open) ? creep
Call: (8) www_browser:command_cache(open, _G397) ? creep
Exit: (8) www_browser:command_cache(open, '/bin/open') ? creep
Call: (8) '/bin/open'\== (-) ? creep
Exit: (8) '/bin/open'\== (-) ? creep
Exit: (7) www_browser:has_command(open) ? creep
 Call: (7) www_browser:expand_url_path('http://www.bbc.co.uk', _G397)  ?   creep
Call: (8) atomic('http://www.bbc.co.uk') ? creep
Exit: (8) atomic('http://www.bbc.co.uk') ? creep
Exit: (7) www_browser:expand_url_path('http://www.bbc.co.uk',   'http://www.bbc.co.uk') ? creep


^  Call: (7) format(string(_G389), '~w "~w"', [open,  'http://www.bbc.co.uk']) ? creep
^  Exit: (7) format(string("open \"http://www.bbc.co.uk\""), '~w "~w"',  [open, 'http://www.bbc.co.uk']) ? creep
Call: (7) shell("open \"http://www.bbc.co.uk\"") ? creep
Exit: (7) shell("open \"http://www.bbc.co.uk\"") ? creep
Exit: (6) www_browser:www_open_url('http://www.bbc.co.uk') 
? creep
true.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your prolog does three round trips and ends up to use `open` which is probably meant as a fallback for mac users (it isn't the program you want to use in this context). First, it tries to read the browser flag from the prolog environment, then it tries to read the `BROWSER` variable from the systen environment. If those two fail, it looks for a program named `gnome-open`. After that, it looks for a program called open. Here are some ways you'll probably get to the right program:

Try to set the `$BROWSER` variable in the environment you've started prolog in. One possibility is to start your Prolog like this:

```
BROWSER=<your browser command> swipl
```

You also can set it in your `.*shrc` for future use (probably a good idea, because the `BROWSER` variable is something other programs rely on:

```
export BROWSER=<your browser command>
```

Another way is to try and set the browser for prolog: Put this somewhere in your `~/.plrc` to set it for the current user, or somewhere in your prolog files to set it for the current application:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(browser, 'chrome').
```

If those don't help, try installing `gnome-open`.

Comment: Thanks I used export BROWSER=google-chrome and the browser now launches. However the prolog prompt now does not return to '?-' it states: Created new window in existing browser session.
I then give it a full stop and it says: ERROR: Stream user_input:16:1 Syntax error: Unexpected end of clause

Comment: If I trace, the goal does end and I get dropped back at '?-' but not if I run the goal normally..

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the error could be also referred to a SWI-Prolog version. Have you try to install the last development release (7.1.37)?